# Xamarin Android - hide a textview

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

my problem is as follows - I use a toggle button to hide/unhide a TextView. What I get is an empty space when it's hidden.

What I want to get is 'redraw'/'reload' the Layout so instead of just hiding the TextView it's being removed or added to it - without having this empty placeholder in the middle of my layout.

I come from Cordova and was using Angular before. Any help???

```
_addressManual = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.addressManual);

_addressHomeManualToogle.Click += (o, e) => {
    if (_addressHomeManualToogle.Checked)
        _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
    else
        _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can read in https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.ViewStates/ `Visibility` has 3 states:

- `Visible` is just normally showing the object
- `Invisible` keeps the layout but does not draw the element (like Opacity set to 0)
- `Gone` removes the element completely from the object tree

So in your case, you probably want

```
_addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone
```

instead of `Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible`

You can also see [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
_addressManual = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.addressManual);

_addressHomeManualToogle.Click += (o, e) => {
    if (_addressHomeManualToogle.Checked)
        _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
    else
        _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
};
```

Comment: Damn aint fast enough!

Answer (score 1):

use `ViewStates.Gone` to completely hide it

Answer (score 1):

With memory best practices in mind, what you really want to do is this:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        _addressManual = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addressManual);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        _addressHomeManualToogle.CheckedChange += _addressHomeManualToogle_CheckedChange;
        base.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        _addressHomeManualToogle.CheckedChange -= _addressHomeManualToogle_CheckedChange;
        base.OnPause();
    }

    void _addressHomeManualToogle_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsChecked)
            _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
        else
            _addressManual.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
    }
```

Essentially you don't want the event handler to stay hooked up when the view is not visible to the user, giving a chance for the variables to get garbage collected if need be. 
Also the event handler arguments (CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs) already tell you wether the checkbox is checked or not, thus there is no need to keep a reference to _addressHomeManualToogle for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to try with `Visibility.Gone` on you TextView